# How do you install MP3agic?

Tags: java, maven, jar, package, mp3agic

MP3agic: https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic

Example.java: https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mpatric/mp3agic/example/Example.java

I have been programming in java for a few years but have never installed anything extra relating to java (like MP3agic) before, and I have absolutely no idea how to do it. Reading up on websites it seems like it should be as easy as double-clicking on the .jar file, but when I do that with MP3agic I still don't have any luck.

Listed on the link above are brief instructions on how to install it: download and install maven (which I've done correctly), run "mvn lean package" in CMD, then in the newly created 'target' folder there are three jars: mp3agic-0.8.5-SNAPSHOT/SNAPSHOT-javadoc/SNAPSHOT-sources.jar.

At this point I double clicked on them all and assumed it was installed, but when I tried to run an Example.java file made for MP3agic (link at top), Java couldn't compile it.

I have tried added the path of my 'target' folder in the Path Environment Variable, but that hasn't worked. I also don't use something like Eclipse for programming (just Notepad++ and CMD, although that's likely to change)

Comment: Do you have an IDE that you are familiar with? (Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA etc). That would make things a whole lot easier. I was able to clone that git repo and run Example.java very quickly without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the class path during compilation. (I donot use IDE , I use plain CMD + Notepad++)

write something like this :

```
javac -cp mp3agic-0.9.1-SNAPSHOT.jar; Example.java
```

provided both of them are in the same dir.

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

*For people like me:*

**Maven Installation:**

- Download [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) (Zip File)
- Unzip Maven (anywhere)
- Add Maven to system eviorment variables ([help](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/))

**Get MP3agic.jar**

- Download Zip
- Unzip MP3agic (anywhere)
- Open cmd in MP3agic path
- run "mvn clean install"

**Include MP3agic.jar *(IntelliJ)***

- Open project structor
- Add Library -> Choose MP3agic.jar